# Method Overloading with objects implementing same interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

I'm stunned that this doesn't even compile.
This is a test program of the issue i'm having in a WCF service i'm writing (where basically the client sends the wcf service a list of different tasks, i'm then server-side processing that list of different tasks, and need to run different methods for each obviously).

> Compilation error :  cannot convert from 'UserQuery.IMyInterface' to
>   'UserQuery.MyObj1'

```
public interface IMyInterface{};

public class MyObj1 : IMyInterface{};
public class MyObj2 : IMyInterface{};


public String Process(MyObj1 obj)
{
return "did one";
}
public String Process(MyObj2 obj)
{
return "did two";
}

void Main()
{

    IMyInterface obj = new MyObj1();
    var s = Process(obj);

    s.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Why sould your main-class be provided with functionality for both `MyObj1` and `MyObj2`? Shouldn´t those handle this on their own? Your design has some strange flaws which we cannot solve probably as long as you do not say why you need these two methods where they are.

Comment: You're stunned that there is no automatic type conversion from a *less* specific type to a *more* specific type? What programming background do you come from? Python? Objective-C? C# isn't a "true" OOP language, it has a lot of static type checking.

Comment: @Luaan > When you think about it statically it makes sense indeed. Kept thinking at runtime i'd see the instanceof the object and run the correct overload. Forgot it would be linked statically.

Comment: @HimBromBeere > It's what i would have done normally.
But those objects are DTO's defined in a common library. So it made more sense to code all the work in a helper class called in the WCF service. Since i have about 30 of those, encapsulating each dto in a new class with the process method seemed like a lot of plumbing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to expliciltely cast `obj` to `MyObj1` as the compiler does not know that you assign an instance of that class to `obj`.

```
IMyInterface obj = new MyObj1();
var s = Process((MyObj1) obj);
```

The actual type of `obj` is only known at runtime.

A better appraoch would be two define the method `Process` on your interface itself:

```
IMyInterface {
    public string Process();
}
```

Now your two classes implement this by:

```
class MyObj1 : IMyInterface {
    public string Process() { return "did one" ; }
}
```

Thus you do not even have to pass that instance to the method.

Comment: So i'll have to create a factory class so my service can call the correct overloaded method ? :(

Would it not be possible to use some kind of run-time reflection ?

Comment: @ZARk you could pass the `interface` type as the parameter and call a method on that instance

Comment: solved it !!  Used the new "dynamic" keyword
`dynamic a = Convert.ChangeType(obj, obj.GetType());
var s = Process(a);`

Comment: Seems pretty cumbersome to make use of `dynamic` here the way you do IMO. I would not recommend it.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dynamic:  "The dynamic keyword influences compilation. A dynamic variable can have any type. Its type can change during runtime. The downside is that performance suffers and you lose compile-time checking."

Perhaps is not the best solution.

Comment: @ZARk Umm, where exactly is that "factory class" of yours? HimBromBeere doesn't imply anything like that. Even the way you use `dynamic` to "solve" this is very weird (why the `Convert.ChangeType`?). What kind of programming experience do you have, Python? I think you're making a lot of assumptions that aren't true, and then writing "weird" code based on those assumptions. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use open generics with [type constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)? No need for casting, no need for factory classes or anything *hacky*.

```
public string Process<T>(T obj)
  where T : IMyInterface
{
    ...
}
```

Call it like

```
IMyInterface obj = new MyObj1();
var s = Process(obj);
```

as intended.

Comment: You can omit the type-contraint on `IMyInterface` as `MyObj1` already implements it.

Comment: He uses IMyInterface obj, not var obj.  :-)